# Removing numbers in url key/product url magento1?

Tags: magento-1.9

My site shows http://127.0.0.1/magento/index.php/c/spyder-5.in category name added numbers.How to find out these problem?. Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

That's probably because the url is not **Unique**.

Magento appends these numbers to the end of your URLs, because it actually already exists.

Go into admin at:

```
Catalog > Url Rewrite Management
```

And there you'll find all your urls and a way to manage them.

There's another option:

Access Your Database search for table “core_url_rewrite”. Do a search to find anything containing the URL in question. It will return all the results containing the rows you want to remove.

Delete all of these rows, removing all existence of the URL you want to get rid of and run the reindex from command line or

```
System > Index Management
```

Go to your category and save it once more.

Comment: Thanks obsergiu sir .I truncate the Core_url_rewrite table and reindex Catalog URL Rewrites  but it does not remove random number .How to  overcome  this problem?

Comment: Hi @DileepKumar,  do you have multiple store views? Go into root categories and check your category per each store view. Make sure you have unique urls in every store view. Edit/save them and then truncate the table and reindex everything. I'm sure it will work.

Comment: Hi @obsergiu, i have following your instructions, but its not working.How to find these problem.Can you please help me?

Comment: Check if Categories have unique URL then go into `Catalog > Url Rewrite Management` and  make sure all the urls for categories are deleted (if not just delete them) go into  `System > Index Management` and reindex  `Catalog Url Rewrites` it will recreate all the deleted redirects without duplicates.

Comment: Hi@obsergiu, I have followed your instructions and catalog->url rewrite management all the URLs for categories are deleted.After going into System->Index management and reindexing the catalog URL rewrites.But it is also not working .Can you please help me?